# Cannot build custom action in ROS2

Tags: linux, python-3.6, action, ros2

I want to create a custom Action client/server for my ROS2 project in Ubuntu 18.04. I am following the answer from https://answers.ros.org/question/3234... in order to create a ROS2 pkg for the custom action.

My package looks like this:

```
action_interface
  action
    PlanAid.action
  package.xml
  CMakeTests.txt
```

My files are as following:
**PlanAid.action**:

```
#goal definition
string request
string problem
---
#result definition
string data
string event
---
#feedback
string feedback
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(action_interface)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  # we dont use add_compile_options with pedantic in message packages
  # because the Python C extensions dont comply with it
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(action_msgs REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  action/PlanAid.action
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs action_msgs
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()
```

And **package.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>action_interface</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>ros action custom action interface</description>
  <maintainer email="skanda.naglapur-ramamurthy@man.eu">Skanda Naglapur Ramamurthy</maintainer>
  <license>MIT</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>action_msgs</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>action_msgs</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

When I try to build my workspace with:

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

I receive the following error:

```
[Processing: action_interface]                             
--- stderr: action_interface                                       
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rosidl_generator_py/action_interface/libaction_interface__python.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/action_interface__python.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rosidl_generator_py/action_interface/action_interface_action_s__rosidl_typesupport_c.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/action_interface_action__rosidl_typesupport_c__pyext.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< action_interface   [ Exited with code 2 ]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt look about right. Have you done `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`? Perhaps you could build by now

Comment: It seems like you should be adding the -fPIC to compile settings, either in the main project or possibly in your CMakeLists.txt above by adding to the set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...) flags. I find -fPIC is usually enabled by default so what platform are you on, a microcontroller? PIC allows objects in .so or ..a to be relocated so they  dont clash during link time or at runtime (when all sections of a process image are being loaded by MMU)